# How can I fix “standard_init_linux.go:187: exec user process caused "exec format error"” in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pocketmine

I have just made my first ever Docker Image to run pmmp/PocketMine-MP inside of Docker. When I try to the the container I get the following error:

```
[root@docker pmmp-docker]# docker run -it -p 19132:19132 -p 19132:19132/udp --name pmmp pmmp
standard_init_linux.go:187: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I have a Dockerfile setup too:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install curl git

RUN curl -O https://jenkins.pmmp.io/job/PHP-7.2-Linux-x86_64/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/PHP_Linux-x86_64.tar.gz

RUN mkdir -p server

RUN tar xf PHP_Linux-x86_64.tar.gz --directory ./server

RUN curl -O https://jenkins.pmmp.io/job/PocketMine-MP/Development/artifact/PocketMine-MP_1.7dev-615_45b02d92_API-3.0.0-ALPHA10.phar > ./server/PocketMine-MP.phar 

RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmmp/PocketMine-MP/master/start.sh > ./server/start.sh

RUN chmod +x ./server/start.sh

CMD ["./server/start.sh", "--no-wizard", "--enable-rcon=on"]
```

How can I fix this? I am very new and if I am already putting myself into a hole of failure please tell me.

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` on your docker host?

Comment: Typically, this means the binary was compiled for a different kind of system than what you're running. x86_64, for example, is used by Intel and AMD -- if your hardware is, say, a Raspberry Pi or somesuch... well, there you are.

Comment: As such, it's not a Docker-specific question, or even a software-development-related question -- anyone installing software compiled for the wrong kind of hardware (or otherwise using an unsupported ABI) can get this.

Comment: @larsks Linux docker 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

No further insights, but I fixed my issues by doing a factory reset of Docker.

[image]